# Undefined variable,index error fetching data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

Im fetching data from a table to another table that will be shown in my dashboard page for a user after loggin in.

**But there is a problem with the indexes, i got this error:**

[image]

Here is the line error:

[image]

***Here is my code:***

My view file ("usuario"):

```
                    <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </thead>


<tbody>
    <?php

    if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record['id']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['User']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['name']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['grade']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['date']."</td>
                  </tr>";
        }

       }
    ?>

</tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller file ("login"):

```
    public function home(){

    $data['record']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
    $this->load->view('usuario',$data);
}
```

My model file ("m_login"):

```
        public function getDetails()
        {
            $st=$this->db->SELECT('cursadas.*, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name')->from('cursadas')
                ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
                ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
                ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
                ->get()->result_array();
            return $st[0]; 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable `$records` on view but not on controller

Change

```
$data['record'] = $this->m_login->getDetails();
```

To

```
// add this array() just in case no results found 

$data['records'] = array(); 
$data['records'] = $this->m_login->getDetails();

$this->load->view('usuario', $data);
```

Another way is on controller

```
$results = $this->m_login->getDetails();

$data['records'] = array(); 

if ($results) {
   foreach ($results as $result) {
      $data['records'][] = array(
         'id' => $result['id'],
         'User' => $result['User'],
         'name' => $result['name'],
         'grade' => $result['grade'],
         'date' => $result['date']
      );
   }
}

$this->load->view('usuario',$data);
```

View

```
<?php if ($records) {?>
<?php foreach($records as $record) {?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $record['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['User'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['grade'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['date'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr> 
<td>No Results Found</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong array index in your controller.

Change this

```
$data['record']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
```

to

```
 $data['records']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
```

Comment: Remove that  && $records != false from if statement

Answer (score 0):

result_array() return returns result with array so you need to it like this -

```
if (count($record) > 0 && $record != false) {
    foreach($record as $rec){
        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$rec['id']."</td>
                  <td>".$rec['User']."</td>
                  <td>".$rec['name']."</td>
                  <td>".$rec['grade']."</td>
                  <td>".$rec['date']."</td>
              </tr>";
    }
   }
```

Please check this from above code and comment if you have any problem

Comment: Can you paste array of result means - you need to echo "<pre>"; print_r($recoord); echo "</pre>"; after foreach and before echo "</tr>

Comment: yes add ; after echo "</pre>"; and exit; then run the app

Comment: Same error dude, take a look:
https://i.gyazo.com/76acb013bf47781a945469d9b76ecf7b.png
https://i.gyazo.com/e3493b737e283ed803246f7e2f9b129f.png

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($records); echo "<pre>"; exit;  paste this line before if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) { and paste output

Comment: I did this:
https://i.gyazo.com/f0d421c13da822de17d23aa25043a776.png
Error:
https://i.gyazo.com/0a9fc1dc99ed899a6af8cdb42fda967d.png
https://i.gyazo.com/f3007ac3c17ca324fe3f53298c420046.png

:(

Comment: change records from record in this line - "<pre>"; print_r($records); echo "<pre>"; exit; you are return record not records; if still you have problem start debugging from model

Comment: Nothing happened dude,do not know what to do:S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141248/discussion-between-ryan-and-programming-guy).